# In Spring Boot, how do you URL query properties of embedded objects?

Tags: java, spring-boot

There is a `Customer` object and an `Address` object `@Embedded` inside of the `Customer` object. `Address` has the field `USState` and `Customer` has the field `name`.

When one does `customers?name=Bob` an Example object is constructed `new Customer("name", null, null)` but for `customers?USState=IL` the wrong Example object is constructed: `new Customer(null, null, null)` instead of `new Customer(null, null, new Address(null, null, "IL", null))`.

How does one persuade Spring Boot to recognize URL queries of properties of `@Embedded` objects, assuming the field names of `Address` do not collide with any of the field names of `Customer`?

Comment: What did you try? Please share a [example].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with `customers?addressUSState=IL`  considering that your Address object on Customer object has a field with name address.

Comment: `customers?address.USState=IL` does give the desired result, but there ought to be a way to get rid of the `address`

Comment: what technology of spring boot you use? spring-webflow?

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-web`